# ionic 3 - how to control scroll speed

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to control the max speed at which a user can scroll through an ion-list. I have not been able to find anything on this in the ionic documentation. How is this achieved in Ionic 3? Thanks in advance.

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.2.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0
```

Comment: Hi, Did you get anything related to scroll speed in ionic 3?

Comment: Unfortunately, I never got an answer to this.